# How to count values in cells of a column if the values are greater than cells of adjacent column

Tags: excel

I want an excel formula that will count the number of cells in say Column B that have values greater than the values in their adjacent cells in Column A. eg) if B2>A2 then this will be one count. Like this count of all the cells in column B

Comment: What have you tried?  Give us some background.

Comment: I looked up sumproduct plus countif formula but not able to get the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2:B1000>A2:A1000))
```

Comment: Out of interest, I used `=SUM(--(B1:B9>A1:A9))` and it gave me the correct answer on my test set. Is there a difference in this case using `SUM` vs `SUMPRODUCT`?

Comment: @AlexP - depending on the version of Excel, your formula needs to be confirmed with CSE.

Comment: @AlexP SUMPRODUCT is a natural Array formula and as such in earlier versions than office 365 subscription it does not need to use CSE.  With the advent of Dynamic Array formulas, Excel did away with the need to use CSE in most cases.  Basically they do the same thing.  SUMPRODUCt just does not require the CSE in the older versions like SUM does.

Comment: For the uninitiated, *CSE* = `CTRL` + `SHIFT` + `ENTER`